# Adding the result of computation as an argument in Scheme

Tags: scheme, syntax-error, square-root

I try to do a program that calculates the square of a number in Scheme but it gives me as an error that I gave the **abs** procedure two arguments instead of one. This is my first program in Scheme and  have no clue how to do it. I tried to change the position of the brackets but it doesn't work.

```
(define (square X)
    (try 1 X))


(define (try guess X)
    (if (good-enaugh? guess X)
        guess
        ((try improve guess X) X)))


(define (good-enaugh? guess X)
    (< (abs(- (* guess guess) X)) 0.0001))


(define (improve guess X)
    (/(+ (/ X guess) guess) 2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. The problem is that the second branch of your conditional in `try` has a pair of parentheses too much.

```
(define (try guess X)
    (if (good-enaugh? guess X)
        guess
        ((try improve guess X) X)))
```

Should become:

```
(define (try guess X)
    (if (good-enaugh? guess X)
        guess
        (try (improve guess X) X)))
```

You make a call to the function `try`. The first parameter is the result of `(improve guess X)` and the second argument is the number `X`. Notice that I also changed the parenthesis around the call to `improve`. The way you wrote it was calling the function `try` with as first argument the function `improve`, second argument `guess` and third argument `X`.

## Full source

For good measure the complete source is listed below.

```
(define (square X)
    (try 1 X))


(define (try guess X)
    (if (good-enaugh? guess X)
        guess
        (try (improve guess X) X)))


(define (good-enaugh? guess X)
    (< (abs(- (* guess guess) X)) 0.0001))


(define (improve guess X)
    (/(+ (/ X guess) guess) 2))


> (square 13)
3,....
```

[Link to repl.it](http://repl.it/hh9/1)

Comment: Now it gives me as error "Error: execute: unbound symbol: "good-enough?" [square, try]". I'm using [link](repl.it) as an interpreter.

Comment: Oh right, I changed the name to the correct English spelling. I will modify.

Comment: I added the changes and it told me that **abs** has two arguments instead of one. I did this " (< (abs (abs (* abs(guess) guess)) X)) 0.001)" as a workaround and then it told me that "1 is not a function".

Comment: What kind of dialect are you using? R5RS? R6RS?

Comment: I have added a link to the repl.it instance that holds this code. It works fine.